# About pointer to member function of derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, derived-class, member-functions

Here's my code, and the IDE is DEV C++11

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        int a=15;
};
class B:public A
{

};
int main(){

    int A::*ptr=&B::a; //OK
    int B::*ptr1=&A::a; //why?
    int B::A::*ptr2=&B::a;//why?
    int B::A::*ptr3=&A::a;  //why?

}
```

I have read Programming Languages — C++ and I know the type of `&B::a` is `int A::*`, but I don't realise why the next three lines will pass the compilation.
And the weirdest thing to me is the syntax of  `int B::A::*` , what's the meaning of this? I'm just a newcomer of `C/C++`, so please tolerate my weird question.

Comment: @Ron Ahem.. It **is** [mcve]. `ptr` is of type `int A::*`, `ptr2` is of type `int B::A::*`, etc.. As you can see: the code posted by OP [compiles just fine](http://ideone.com/Cz2Bmg), they are just confused about **why** it compiles.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius True. I stand corrected.

Comment: Why do you think they shouldn't pass compilation?

Comment: I would assume that the `int B::A::*` is just a level of indirection that is actually `int A::*`.

Answer (score 1):

Diagram representation may help you understand why it is ok and compiles 
[image: int A::*ptr = &B::a;]

[image: int B::*ptr1 = &A::a;]

[image: int B::A::*ptr2 = &B::a;]

[image: int B::A::*ptr3 = &A::a]

Interesting will be once you reinitialize the same variable in inherited class

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int a = 15;
};
class B :public A
{
public:
    int a = 10;
};
int main() {

    int A::*ptr = &B::a; //Waring class B a value of type int B::* cannot be 
                         //used to initialize an entity of type 'int A::*'
    int B::*ptr1 = &A::a; // why?
    int B::A::*ptr2 = &B::a;//Waring class B a value of type int B::* cannot                            
                      // be used to initialize an entity of type 'int A::*'
    int B::A::*ptr3 = &A::a;  //why?

}
```